# json_decode PHP cURL post to API .NET

Tags: php, rest, post, curl

From PHP I post to an API on .NET (Win Server), using cURL

My last part of code is:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$responseArray = json_decode($response, true);
```

When I do:

```
print_r($response);
```

I get in the browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Length: 64 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2015 12:44:50 GMT {"resultCode":0,"resultMessage":"Success","order_number":123456}
```

When I do:

```
print_r($responseArray);
```

I get blank screen.

So my question is how do I grab the variables from this response?

Comment: It appears that you're getting the headers in your output/response. You can turn that off `CURLOPT_HEADER, 0` if you're not doing so already. Also try `var_dump($response)` -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try setting the curlopt to not return Output Headers.

[PHP: curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

The item you would set is `CURLOPT_HEADER`
Example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

At that point, your response ($response) should be the JSON-encoded string.
For added bonus you may also want to enforce JSON output expectation if you're not currently using that setting.

```
// Set The Response Format to Json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
```

More info here: [PHP Curl, Request data return in application/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939326/php-curl-request-data-return-in-application-json)

Comment: I realized after a closer look. Thx anyway.

Comment: I commented out curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);